# How to compute the expectation?

Tags: probability

If there are six events $A_1, A2, \dots, A_6$ and the probability of each event are $1/6$, that is $\mathbb{P}(X_1=A_i)$. Then what is the expectation of $X_1$? Is the 
$$1\mathbb{P}(X_1=A_1)+2\mathbb{P}(X_1=A_2)+\dots+6\mathbb{P}(X_1=A_6)?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite. The definition of the expectation of a discrete random variable $X$ with possible values $A_1,\dots,A_k$ is
$$
\Bbb E(X) = \sum_{j=1}^k A_j \Bbb P(X=A_j).
$$
In this case, therefore, the expectation will be
$$
\sum_{j=1}^6 A_j \Bbb P(X=A_j) = \sum_{j=1}^6 A_j \frac16 = \frac{A_1+A_2+A_3+A_4+A_5+A_6}6.
$$

Comment: How about the $A_1=(1,1)$ $A_2=(1,0)$ and so on? Just plus these points?